# TCP Gateway with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to implement a tcp gateway that sends a message to a server and receive synchronously the response.

The server is up and running on a specific port so following the examples I have found on the web I have configured it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class TcpClientConfig {

    @Value("${tcp.server.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${tcp.server.port}")
    private int port;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpClientConfig.class);


    @Component
    @MessagingGateway
    public interface TcpClientGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel="outboundChannel")
        byte[] sendByClient(byte[] message);
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
        Bytearraylengthheaderserializer serDeser = new Bytearraylengthheaderserializer(2);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(serDeser);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(serDeser);
        return tcpNioClientConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow incomingClient(final TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpReceivingChannelAdapter,
                                          TcpServerEndpoint tcpServerEndpoint) {

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(tcpReceivingChannelAdapter)
                .handle(message -> { LOGGER.info("RECEIVING ON CLIENT: {}", tcpServerEndpoint.processMessage((byte[]) message.getPayload()));})
                .get();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outgoingClient(final MessageChannel outboundChannel, final TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingClientMessageHandler) {

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(outboundChannel)
                .handle(tcpSendingClientMessageHandler)
                .get();
    }



    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingClientMessageHandler(AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {

        TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingMessageHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        tcpSendingMessageHandler.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
        tcpSendingMessageHandler.setClientMode(true);
        tcpSendingMessageHandler.setRetryInterval(5000);
        tcpSendingMessageHandler.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        return tcpSendingMessageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpReceivingChannelAdapter(AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {

        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpReceivingChannelAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        tcpReceivingChannelAdapter.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
        tcpReceivingChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        tcpReceivingChannelAdapter.setClientMode(true);
        tcpReceivingChannelAdapter.setRetryInterval(5000);
        return tcpReceivingChannelAdapter;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void open(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Open new connection to Router {}", event.getConnectionId());
        clientConnectionFactory().getConnection().getSocketInfo().getChannel()
                .setOption(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 60);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void close(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Close connection to Router {}", event.getConnectionId());
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a Gateway that send the message and wait synchronously for the response. But when I call the method of the gateway

```
byte[] sendByClient(byte[] message)
```

the call get hanged and there's no response back to the gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TcpSendingMessageHandler` is a one-way component. It just does not wait for any replies to produce them to the `replyChannel` header for that `TcpClientGateway` in the beginning of the flow.

Consider to use a `TcpOutboundGateway` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-gateways

This samples has some basic ideas what and how to do with the gateway: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/tcp-client-server